# Reference request for a particular type of evolutionary problems

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

I am currently interested in the system of equations of the form,
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{du}{dt} + Au\ni f(u)\\[0.2cm]
u(0)=u_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

where the operator $A:D(A)\subset X\to X^*$ is nonlinear, $X$ is a Banach space and the functional $f=f(u)$ is linear.

I know some of the wellposedness results for the nonhomogeneous problems where the RHS term $f=f(t)$. I am also aware of some results for the evolution equations (as above) for semilinear equations where $A$ is linear and $f=f(u)$ is nonlinear. Can somebody point out some references / articles / books which discusses the type of evolution equation which I mentioned. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the following recent paper and the references therein

> COMPACT ALMOST AUTOMORPHIC WEAK SOLUTIONS FOR SOME MONOTONE DIFFERENTIAL INCLUSIONS: APPLICATIONS TO PARABOLIC AND HYPERBOLIC EQUATIONS, B. Es-sebbar et al. (2019).

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look.